# Is there a way to use the SendKeys VB function or keybd_event User32 library function to send a single Shift keystroke by itself?

Tags: vba, automation, voice-recognition, user32, naturallyspeaking

I am using a voice recognition add-on to Dragon NaturallySpeaking to create keystroke automations using my voice. The add-on exposes the VB function `SendKeys`. I am aware that the shift key modifier (`+`) can be combined with almost any other character(s), but I am not trying to combine the shift key with anything; I simply want to send a single shift keypress without anything else. Is this possible?

Some things I've tried:

```
SendKeys "+"

SendKeys "{Shift}"
```

Any ideas?

UPDATE:

Based on the [article](https://winsourcecode.blogspot.com/2019/06/simulates-printscreen-key-sendkeys.html?m=1) posted by [user14797724](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14797724/user14797724), it's use of the keybd_event User32 library function, and the [documentation for the System.Windows.Forms.Keys enumeration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.keys?view=net-5.0), I modified the code to use left shift. Here's the code:

```
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
Imports System.Windows.Forms

Public Module SendWinKey
    Const KEYEVENTF_KEYDOWN As Integer = &H0
    Const KEYEVENTF_KEYUP As Integer = &H2

    Declare Sub keybd_event Lib "User32" (ByVal bVk As Byte, ByVal bScan As Byte, ByVal dwFlags As UInteger, ByVal dwExtraInfo As UInteger)

Public Sub Main()    
        keybd_event(CByte(Keys.LShiftKey), 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYDOWN, 0) 'press the left shift key down
        keybd_event(CByte(Keys.LShiftKey), 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0) 'release the left shift key
End Sub

End Module
```

I was hoping this would work for me but it appears that the scripting environment I am using does not support the Imports keyword and requires [CLS-Compliant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/language-independence-and-language-independent-components) variables for an external call. I might be able to get around the Imports keyword problem by prefixing the appropriate types with their full namespace but **does anybody have an alternative external call I might make that is CLS-Compliant?** The [UInteger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/data-types/uinteger-data-type) type seems to be the one it doesn't like.

UPDATE 2:

I don't know what I was thinking when I put VBScript as one of my tags. I had tagged VBA but someone edited it out. As best I can tell the "language" I am using is a subset of Visual Basic. Here is a screenshot of the editor.

[image: KnowBrainer Command Editor]

Comment: The Shift key is a modifier, just like Ctrl and Alt. It doesn't do anything by itself - it only works when combined with another keystroke. It has no purpose by itself. It isn't actually a keystroke, it's a key state (either pressed or not pressed). What exactly would you expect a modifier key to do without something to modify?

Comment: I have no idea why you would ask, other than the information you've provided in your question text. If you had included that information, I wouldn't have had to ask you for it, would I? Don't blame me because you failed to provide details. It doesn't change what I said anyway; SendKeys won't send keystrokes that aren't valid keystrekes, and a modifier by itself is not a valid keystroke.

Comment: Not angry at all. They're not valid as far as SendKeys is concerned. It will not send them. As I've explained previously, Shift is a modifier key that doesn't do anything on its own except set a state (pressed or not pressed). SendKeys does not work for those types of keys alone.

Comment: https://winsourcecode.blogspot.com/2019/06/simulates-printscreen-key-sendkeys.html?m=1 should do this.

Comment: Are you looking for a vbscript, VBA, VB6 or VB.Net solution? The code snippet you posted is definitely not vbscript.

Comment: You are absolutely right. I don't know what I was thinking when I put VBScript. I had tagged VBA but someone edited it out. As best I can tell it is a subset of Visual Basic. I'll update my original post with a screenshot of the editor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, what he said. I can see where you put some thought into your answer. I suggest that you add comments beside the 160 to explain where that comes from.

Comment: That's a good point. Welcome to the community.

Answer (score 2):

So it turns out that I could substitute the Integer type for the UInteger type. Then I had to figure out how to eliminate the CByte call and the System.Windows.Forms.Keys enumeration. Lastly I just removed the unnecessary Module declaration and everything seems to be working perfectly now. And yes I did repeat the key up and key down events because I actually wanted to hit the shift key twice. Thanks to all who tried to help.

```
'Press and release the left shift key twice

Const LSHIFT As Byte = 160 'Defined here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.keys?view=net-5.0
Const KEYEVENTF_KEYDOWN As Integer = &H0
Const KEYEVENTF_KEYUP As Integer = &H2

Declare Sub keybd_event Lib "User32" (ByVal bVk As Byte, ByVal bScan As Byte, ByVal dwFlags As Integer, ByVal dwExtraInfo As Integer)

Sub Main()    
  keybd_event(LSHIFT, 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYDOWN, 0) 'press the left shift key down
  keybd_event(LSHIFT, 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0) 'release the left shift key
  keybd_event(LSHIFT, 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYDOWN, 0) 'press the left shift key down
  keybd_event(LSHIFT, 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0) 'release the left shift key
End Sub
```